# Unknown column in 'having clause':

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm working on a project where I have many users, and a user has many posts. I'm trying to get the users that have a post count over a certain threshold, but the query I'm using doesn't seem to work.

```
User.where(id: user_ids)
       .where(has_posts: true)
       .joins(:posts)
       .group('users.id')
       .having('COUNT(posts.id) >= user.post_threshold')
```

However with this query I get `Unknown column posts.id in 'having clause':`

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doing this I get the error `invalid use of group function`

Comment: Please append `.to_sql` to the very end of this code and post the result here.

Comment: Also, `>= user.post_threshold` should likely be `>= users.post_threshold` (note `s` in `users`.)

Comment: Sorry, should be using `having`. You should select `post.id` and `user.post_threshold` before using `having`.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Like: http://pastebin.com/raw/Z3wsjpDz

Comment: @user2320239 Have working? I don't have environment Ruby to test. I think it working with your case.

Comment: No sorry that doesn't work, it says `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' user.post_threshold) AS count_post_id_user_post_threshold, companies.id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `posts.*` notation, at least in Postgres, don't know about mysql.

```
User.where(id: user_ids)
 .where(has_posts: true)
 .joins(:posts)
 .group(:id)
 .having('COUNT(posts.*) >= users.post_threshold')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `having` for that, a simple `where` will serve you well:

```
User.
  where(id: user_ids).
  where(has_posts: true).
  where('COUNT(posts.id) >= users.post_threshold').
  joins(:posts).
  group('users.id')
```

Edit: On some databases, you might need to include the aggregation in a select, adding this line to the chain:

```
.select('*, COUNT(posts.id)')
```

Comment: He shouldn't need the group either.  I think he was just using that to have the having clause.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it returned #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000fd68620> rather than the users

Comment: It returned a result set, which is called Relation in Rails. Individual entries in the set should be Users: try `result.first.class`. If it is empty, it means that there is no user that has that many posts.